# How to build a Firefox addon to always show bookmark-stored-details (e.g. tags) for current tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Problem**

In Firefox, when the current tab contains a bookmarked page, I need to always see details stored in the corresponding bookmark (Name, Folder, Tags, etc.), **without** a single additional click.

I need help on how to solve this (seemingly solvable) problem.

Possible solutions:

- Show bookmark details as text appended to the title bar
- Show bookmark details through controls dynamically built on a dedicated toolbar

**Technical questions**

1. Is there an event fired when a bookmark [for the current tab] is changed? Can an addon respond to such an event?
2. Can an addon modify the text shown in the title bar for the current tab?
3. Can someone provide a link to the source code for a simple, ~modern, addon which adds a toolbar? I know / use S3 Download Statusbar but this one is quite advanced for my Firefox development skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice idea.

This is how to get the tags for a url.

```
var navBookmarksService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
var urlToCheckIfBookmarked = 'https://www.bing.com/';
var uri = Services.io.newURI(urlToCheckIfBookmarked, null, null);
console.log(navBookmarksService.isBookmarked(uri)) //this line tells you if the url is bookmarked

var taggingSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/tagging-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsITaggingService);
var tags = taggingSvc.getTagsForURI(uri)
console.log(tags)
```

See the tagging service: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsITaggingService

> Is there an event fired when a bookmark [for the current tab] is changed? Can an addon respond to such an event?

yes you have to use bookmark observer service:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsINavBookmarksService#beginUpdateBatch%28%29
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Bookmarks#Observing_changes_to_bookmarks_and_tags

> Can an addon modify the text shown in the title bar for the current tab?

Yes. You can either change the title of the document loaded. Or get the DOMWindow and modify it's title attribute. IE: `document.querySelector('#main-window').setAttribute('title','rawr')`

Comment: btw the `main-window` code above actually just changes the windows title if you want to change the title of the tab element than o this: `gBrowser.selectedTab.visibleLabel = 'rawr'`